# How to get at compile time the offset of a thread_local variable

Tags: c++, gcc, thread-local

Using gcc under linux, I am searching for a way to get the offset of a thread local variable relative the the thread local storage area.
That offset is what is contained in the object file compiled.
In my opinion there should be a macro or built_in in order to get it.

The code that gives at runtime is as follows in the code bellow. What I need is to get that constant at compile time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

thread_local int x;

template<typename T>
intptr_t getOffset(T& t){
    return (intptr_t)&t-(intptr_t)pthread_self();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{       
    std::cout<<"offset:"<<getOffset<int>(x)<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: According to [the ELF thread-local storage spec](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/tls.pdf) the offset is not determined until runtime because it is dependent upon the order in which modules load and the size of the architecture-specific TCB (which is not known at compile time since you may run the binary on different versions of the OS each of which has a different TCB).

Comment: @RaymondChen By doing objdump of the file compiled after adding some multiplication instructions, I clearly see from the dump  that the offset is specified in the compiled code ( in that case is -4 ). So in the specific case it is known at compile time. So the binary has only one interpration in that case                                                40153d:       64 8b 14 25 fc ff ff    mov    %fs:0xfffffffffffffffc,%edx
  401544:       ff 
  401545:       64 8b 04 25 fc ff ff    mov    %fs:0xfffffffffffffffc,%eax
  40154c:       ff

Comment: @RaymondChen I suspect he _may_ be able to rely on this offset in some cases (see my answer). This would not justify full support in compiler though.

Answer (score 0):

> In my opinion there should be a macro or built_in in order to get it.

Such macro would not be easy/cheap to implement. First of all you can only determine such offset when compiling the executable because for dynamic library it would depend on library's relative position in dependency list of executable that loads it (or even not be in static TLS block if library is loaded dynamically via `dlopen`, hence not accessible via constant offset from TCB).

Now, even you try to determine the offset in executable, you can only do it for `thread_local` variables in executable itself because sizes of thread_local segments for libraries (and their offsets) are determined only at program startup (that's probly because version of loaded library may be newer than one that executable was linked against and thus `thread_local` segment size may be different as well).

Finally even for executable's variables it'll depend on relative order of object files and static/dynamic libraries during the link so you'd need special support in static linker to compute the offset.

You might suggest Binutils developers to consider adding a link-time relocation to compute thread_local offset in executable or even a runtime relocation to compute thread_local in general case but they will require compelling use-cases to consider such proposal.

As a poor man's workaround you can compile your code two times and extract offsets from symtab:

```
$ readelf -sW tmp.o | awk '/TLS/{print $8 " " $2}'
yyy 0000000000000000
xxx 0000000000000004
```